# QML GridLayout analogue to show table model content

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel, qabstracttablemodel

It is possible to use `GridLayout` to show list models content in QML. I need a layout that can show content of table models that return data for row & column (`QAbstractTableModel` - derived classes), not for row & role. How this can be done in Qt?

Comment: [QML TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html)

Comment: maybe you meant [GridView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-gridview.html)? Or one of [these](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#displaying-data-with-views)